# How can I get this value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, opera

I'm working on a opera extension that will search for a specific element on the current page once clicked. But I'm lost and I don't know what to do since I'm a very beginner in html/js stuffs.

The value that I am trying to extract from the page source is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        

      var DEFAULT_URL = '/test/files/db9594e7e810cccdceb2e4faae6339a8.pdf';        

</script>
```

What should I do to extract this kind of attribute value from a pdf viewer link's page source? Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: regex it `/var DEFAULT_URL = '(.*\.pdf)';/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a way to just access window variables from an opera extension... Can't you just access window.DEFAULT_URL since that variable has been set?

As an alternative, you should be able to parse it out manually. The code below will give you all the script tags:

```
document.querySelectorAll("script")
```

If you want to get the content of the first script tag, you should be able to do so with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("script")[0].innerHTML
```

Once you've got that, you should be able to parse and extract the URL that you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting from another file in the directory then try `var DEFAULT_URL = require('/test/files/db9594e7e810cccdceb2e4faae6339a8.pdf')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the pdf page, you can extract the path from url using

`var url = winfow.location.href;`

This is what I understood from your question. Otherwise, please elaborate.